# generated a String from 2 Strings

Tags: c

I begin with my Code
I would like to add a function where the two names that are not identical are connected to a string. For this I would like to use my own function (stringlink that contains two strings as input parameters and generates a third string that contains the two strings connected by an & sign), but how I do this?

And yes I would like to compare two strings without the strcmp function.

Here is my Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    char a[100];
    char b[100];
    int i;
    printf("please enter the first name:");
    scanf("%99s", a);
    printf("please enter the second name:");
    scanf("%99s", b);

    i=0;
    while(a[i] == b[i] && a[i]!='\0')
        i++;

    if ( a ==  b) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: use strchr() or if you want to compare use strcmp(char *str1,char *str2);

Comment: Beside from the question about connection, note that the condition `a ==  b` will always be false because they are (pointers converted from) different arrays.

Comment: 1. Allocate for the new string. ([`strlen()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen) and [`malloc()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) will be useful) 2. Copy and concatenate strings. ([`strcpy()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) and [`strcat()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat) will be useful) 3. Return the resulting string.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `strcmp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you want to take two names, and only if they are not equal, joint them with a `'&'` character using a function, then one convenient option is to define your function to return a pointer to constant static array of characters of size `length_a + length_b + 1` (the `+ 1` to account for the `'&'` character).

You can do that as follows, performing the comparison between `a` and `b` using a pointer to `b` and the index used copying `a` to the linked array, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 100        /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define LINK '&'

const char *strlink (const char *a, const char *b, const char link)
{
    const char *p = b;                      /* pointer to be to compare with a */
    int i = 0, len = 2 * MAXC + 1;          /* index, max length for linked str */
    static char linked[2 * MAXC + 1];       /* static array for return */
    
    if (!a || !b)                           /* validate neither a || b NULL */
        return NULL;
    
    while (i < len-1 && *a && *a != '\n') { /* loop over chars in a */
        if (*a == *p)                       /* compare to chars in b */
            p++;
        linked[i++] = *a++;                 /* assign char from a to linked[index] */
    }
    
    if (p - b == i) {   /* if equal chars in b equal i, strings are the same */
        fputs ("error: string a & b are the same.\n", stderr);
        return NULL;
    }
    
    linked[i++] = link;                     /* add link between strings */
    
    while (i < len-1 && *b && *b != '\n')   /* loop b adding to linked */
        linked[i++] = *b++;
    
    linked[i] = 0;                          /* nul-terminate linked */
    
    return linked;
}
```

(**note:** there is no need to trim the `'\n'` included in the names filled by `fgets()` since the `'\n'` are taken as an end-of-string character in `strlink()`)

Also note, since the array in `strlink()` is a `static` array, it will be overwritten the next time `strlink()` is called, so if you need to preserve each joined string, copy the successfully joined strings to permanent storage.

Then in `main()` you simply need to prompt for the two names and then validate the success or failure of `strlink()` by *checking the return!*. Only after you have validated the return do you print the linked string.

```
int main (void) {
    
    char a[MAXC], b[MAXC];
    const char *linked = NULL;
    
    fputs ("first name  : ", stdout);       /* take user-input with fgets() */
    if (!fgets (a, MAXC, stdin))            /* validate */
        return 0;
    
    fputs ("second name : ", stdout);       /* ditto */
    if (!fgets (b, MAXC, stdin))
        return 0;
    
    if ((linked = strlink (a, b, LINK)))    /* if linked successful, print */
        printf ("linked name : %s\n", linked);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/strlink
first name  : Mickey
second name : Minnie
linked name : Mickey&Minnie
```

If the names are the same:

```
$ ./bin/strlink
first name  : Mickey
second name : Mickey
error: string a & b are the same.
```

Or with whitespace:

```
$ ./bin/strlink
first name  : My dog
second name :  cat
linked name : My dog & cat
```

---

**Returning `int` Instead of `const char *`**

If you must have an `int` return instead of a character type, then making the change is straight forward. Per your comment the function returns `0` on success and `1` in the event the string are equal or in the event of failure. Modifications to the complete code are:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 100        /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define LINK '&'

int strlink (char *linked, const char *a, const char *b, const char link)
{
    const char *p = b;                      /* pointer to be to compare with a */
    int i = 0, len = 2 * MAXC + 1;          /* index, max length for linked str */
    
    if (!a || !b)                           /* validate neither a || b NULL */
        return 1;
    
    while (i < len-1 && *a && *a != '\n') { /* loop over chars in a */
        if (*a == *p)                       /* compare to chars in b */
            p++;
        linked[i++] = *a++;                 /* assign char from a to linked[index] */
    }
    
    if (p - b == i) {   /* if equal chars in b equal i, strings are the same */
        fputs ("error: string a & b are the same.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    
    linked[i++] = link;                     /* add link between strings */
    
    while (i < len-1 && *b && *b != '\n')   /* loop b adding to linked */
        linked[i++] = *b++;
    
    linked[i] = 0;                          /* nul-terminate linked */
    
    return 0;
}

int main (void) {
    
    char a[MAXC], b[MAXC], linked[2 * MAXC + 1];
    
    fputs ("first name  : ", stdout);       /* take user-input with fgets() */
    if (!fgets (a, MAXC, stdin))            /* validate */
        return 0;
    
    fputs ("second name : ", stdout);       /* ditto */
    if (!fgets (b, MAXC, stdin))
        return 0;
    
    if (strlink (linked, a, b, LINK) == 0)  /* if linked successful, print */
        printf ("linked name : %s\n", linked);
}
```

(same output)

---

**With Separate String Comparison Function**

In the original `strlink()` function the check of whether `a` and `b` were equal strings was incorporated within the function. Per your comment, if that is needed as a separate function, the code can be rewritten as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 100        /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define LINK '&'

/** string compare without string.h */
int strcmp_nohdr (const char *a, const char *b)
{
    if (!a && !b) return 0;                 /* both NULL */
    if ( a && !b) return 1;                 /* valid a, but b NULL */
    if (!a &&  b) return -1;                /* valid b, but a NULL */

    for (; *a && *a == *b; a++, b++) {}     /* loop while chars the same */

    return (*a > *b) - (*a < *b);           /* -1 - a sorts before b,
                                             *  0 - strings are equal,
                                             *  1 - b sorts before a.
                                             */
}

int strlink (char *linked, const char *a, const char *b, const char link)
{
    int i = 0, len = 2 * MAXC + 1;          /* index, max length for linked str */
    
    if (!a || !b)                           /* validate neither a || b NULL */
        return 1;
    
    while (i < len-1 && *a && *a != '\n')   /* loop over chars in a */
        linked[i++] = *a++;                 /* assign char from a to linked[index] */
    
    linked[i++] = link;                     /* add link between strings */
    
    while (i < len-1 && *b && *b != '\n')   /* loop b adding to linked */
        linked[i++] = *b++;
    
    linked[i] = 0;                          /* nul-terminate linked */
    
    return 0;
}

int main (void) {
    
    char a[MAXC], b[MAXC], linked[2 * MAXC + 1];
    
    fputs ("first name  : ", stdout);       /* take user-input with fgets() */
    if (!fgets (a, MAXC, stdin))            /* validate */
        return 0;
    
    fputs ("second name : ", stdout);       /* ditto */
    if (!fgets (b, MAXC, stdin))
        return 0;
    
    if (strcmp_nohdr (a, b) == 0) {         /* check if a & b are equal */
        fputs ("error: string a & b are the same.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    
    if (strlink (linked, a, b, LINK) == 0)  /* if linked successful, print */
        printf ("linked name : %s\n", linked);
}
```

(same output)

The `strcmp_nohdr()` function behave exactly the same as `strcmp()` from `string.h`, but requires no header (`.._nohdr`).

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Where is the condition that if they are equal, the return value is 1 and otherwise the return value is 0

Comment: It returns `NULL` on equal or a pointer to the string on a successful join. Changing it is simple if that is what you need. When dealing with character strings, it is always *convenient* to return a pointer to the string. Do you need help changing to  a 0/1 `int` return?

Comment: yes i need help. So I mean there should be an extra function where if they are equal a return value is 1 and otherwise 0

Comment: Oh, okay, right now that is handled in the function itself with the `if (p - b == i)` comparison (where `p - b` is length of characters in `b` that match the total characters in `a` ... index `i`). I'll update with a separate compare function.

Comment: how can i Compare this without strcmp?

Comment: There is no `strcmp()`, there is `strcmp_nohdr()` which is just a function I wrote in response to your comment 2 above. You can rename it if you like. Both the first and second examples use no such function and incorporate similar logic in the `strlink()` function. Why did you unselect this answer?

Comment: Why is here the return value -1 and not 1 ---->                                             if (!a &&  b) return -1;

Comment: Because the return controls the sort order. It is explained in the comment immediately to the right `-1` and `a` sorts before `b`, `0` and they are equal, `1` and `b` sorts before `a`. You can change the `-1` to a `1` and you will have an equal/not equal return, but will lose the sort ability.

Comment: why you use fgets

Comment: @adersat You use `fgets()` for ALL user-input. 90% of the input questions on this site are due to the **misuse** of `scanf()`. `fgets()` consumes an entire line of input -- regardless of the content -- there is no possibility of a *matching-failure*. After reading with `fgets()` you then use `sscanf()` to separate values (or just use a pair of pointers and do it manually). By approaching input this way, you never have to worry about extraneous characters being left in your input stream (e.g. `stdin`) unread -- just waiting to bite you on your next attempted input.

Comment: why len -1,--->while (i < len-1 && *a && *a != '\n') ?

Comment: and means this that they are the same here:if (!a && !b) return 0

Comment: The check of `len - 1` ensures you do not keep adding characters beyond the end of `linked` (saving `+1` character for the `'\0'` character at the end). You know `linked` has `2 * MAXC + 1` characters, so with `len = 2 * MAXC + 1`, checking `len - 1` ensures there is always a character left in `linked`. When you have `!a && !b` that is a check to determine if `/* both NULL */` Checking `!a` is the same as (shorthand for) `a == NULL`.

Comment: is the defina a #define CONSTANTE value ? or which type of define is it

Comment: When you `#define something` you are defining a constant literal `#define MAXC 1024` defines an integer literal which can be used to declare arrays of that size (or for any other purpose). If you `#define foo "My Char LIteral"` then `foo` defines a literal string of characters. (you may use `#define DELIM " \t\n"` to define `DELIM` as a constant string to be used as the delimiters with `strtok()`, etc..) The compiler can infer the type from the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sprintf` to create the third string.

```
char res[201];
sprintf(res, "%s&%s", a, b);
printf("%s\n",res);
```

Or even better, for creating the third string, you could take the length of `a` and `b` so that you don't waste space allocating it. Just rememember an additional space for `&` and `\0` string terminator.

Comment: Depends, where do you need it, in your code you're not using it so I can't know.

Answer (score 1):

> stringlink that contains two strings as input parameters and generates a third string that contains the two strings connected by an & sign), but how I do this?

It appears OP wants to avoid standard functions.

Create loops copying one character at atime.

```
char *stringlink(size_t size, char *dest, const char *a, const char *b) {
  char *d = dest;
  size_t i = 0;
  while (i + 1 < size && *a) {
    *d++ = *a++;
    i++;
  } 
  while (i + 1 < size && *b) {
    *d++ = *b++;
    i++;
  }
  if (i < size) {
    *d  = '\0';
  }
  return dest;
}
```

Comment: @alk Yes. Code amended.